# .htaccess to redirect the root to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Using .htaccess I am trying to redirect requests for the root of a site to a subdir. The three approaches I have tried either fail or leave something to be desired.

This fails with indefinite recursion:

```
Redirect / http://example.org/sub
```

These don't seem to work for a defaulted index.html:

```
Redirect / http://example.org/sub/index.html
Redirect /index.html http://example.org/sub/index.html
```

This works, but leaves the directory at the top level, which necessitates rewriting relative links in the html file:

```
DirectoryIndex http://example.org/sub/index.html
```

So, is there any straightforward way just redirect the root totally to a subfolder and have everything work there? I am trying to avoid the fancier features of .htaccess -- I'd probably just prefer the third alternative if it gets too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In the DocumentRoot of old site have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.org/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this qualifies as using the fancier features of .htaccess, which I'd rather not have to master at this point. So I'll probably stick with DirectoryIndex and rewriting links.

Comment: Nothing fancy on this rule. Also `DirectoryIndex http://example.org/sub/index.html` is incorrect as you need to give a file not URL in DirectoryIndex

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the fix -- it does work, however.  By "fancy" I simply mean using the conditional and rewriting features, as opposed to the "canned" directives.

Comment: Another thing, `DirectoryIndex` only works with landing page. So request of `http://example.org` can be made to open `http://example.org/sub/index.html` but if request comes for `http://example.org/foobar` then `DirectoryIndex` can't handle that. For that you need rule as I suggested. (You can leave `RewriteCond` in above rule and it will still work).